# C# linq to sql - selecting tables dynamically

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, dynamic

I have the following scenario: there are a database that generates a new logTable every year. It started on 2001 and now has 11 tables. They all have the same structure, thus the same fields, indexes,pk's, etc.

I have some classes called managers that - as the name says - manages every operation on this DB. For each different table i have a manager, except for this logTable which i have only one manager.

I've read a lot and tried different things like using ITable to get tables dynamically or an interface that all my tables implements. Unfortunately, i lose strong-typed properties and with that i can't do any searches or updates or anything, since i can't use `logTable.Where(q=> q.ID == paramId)`.

Considering that those tables have the same structure, a query that searches logs from 2010 can be the exact one that searches logs from 2011 and on.

I'm only asking this because i wouldn't like to rewrite the same code for each table, since they are equal on it's structure.

**EDIT**

I'm using Linq to SQL as my ORM. And these tables uses all DB operations, not just select.

Comment: How are tables named? (e.g. Log_2011, Log_2010)

Comment: @AS-CII Yes, just like that (Log_2009, Log_2010, Log_2011 and on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as each of your queries return the same shape, you can use ExecuteQuery<Log>("Select cols From LogTable" + instance). Just be aware that ExecuteQuery is one case where LINQ to SQL allows for SQL Injection. I discuss how to parameterize ExecuteQuery at http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Does-LINQ-to-SQL-eliminate-the-possibility-of-SQL-Injection.

Comment: yes, i was wondering if i should do the ExecuteQuery way. However, isn't Linq's proposal not to use direct sql queries? I think kind goes on the wrong path. Nevertheless, i might end up using it, since there's no direct input that could inject my code.

Comment: True, ExecuteQuery is not LINQy, but sometimes you have to do what you have to do. If you want to go even more dynamic, consider the following post: http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2010/08/02/introduction-to-microsoft-data-dll.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Consider putting all your logs in one table and using [partitioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578580%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to maintain performance.  If that is not feasible you could create a view that unions all the log tables together and use that when selecting log data.  That way when you added a new log table you just update the view to include the new table.

**EDIT** Further to the most recent comment:

Sounds like you need a new DBA if he won't let you create new SPs. Yes I think could define an ILogTable interface and then make your log table classes implement it, but that would not allow you do `GetTable<ILogTable>()`.  You would have to have some kind of DAL class with a method that created a union query, e.g.

```
public IEnumerable<ILogTable> GetLogs()
{
    var Log2010 = from log in DBContext.2010Logs
                  select (ILogTable)log;
    var Log2011 = from log in DBContext.2011Logs
                  select (ILogTable)log;
    return Log2010.Concat(Log2011);
}
```

Above code is completely untested and may fail horribly ;-)

Edited to keep @AS-CII happy ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not the DBA and i can't make any changes without consulting him. I liked the view idea. Can you provide me a simple example? I've tried to create an interface that all my log views would inherit, but even this didnt work.

Comment: If your DBA crates the view as described you can then just drag it into the designer window from the server explorer window in VS and an appropriate type will be created.  Simples ;-)

Comment: would i be able to do all DB operations (insert, delete, update, etc) just by adding this view? I must do other operations than select only.

Comment: No you would not be able to insert into the view.  You could however have stored procedures that inserted/updated/deleted from the correct table.  You can wire the SP calls up to the add/delete/update events on the data context to make this process transparent.

Comment: yes, i got confused when you used the term 'view', because i'm working with asp.net mvc3. I know that views are only results of a pre-defined select. But then, i can't use SP too. It's a rule i can't pass over. Is there no way to use ITable interface or to create a class that all tables inherits and then create a method to return this base class? Last time i tried to do it by using `GetTable<T>().Where(q => q.ID == logId);` i got a runtime exception saying that my base class was not mapped as a table.

Comment: while this works for a simple select, it doesnt for a more complex query. Not to mention that i'd need to do some casts from ILogTable to each of my real LogTables. I'm still struggling against it and hopefully i'll come with an answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Tell you DBA to use table partitioning, it is the correct way to go about splitting log tables up and would solve all your problem in a stroke.

Comment: @AS-CII Perhaps but with log tables there are not going to be duplicates so they would both do the same thing.

Comment: It could be true but what about performance? Why would you use a method that does extra-operations? Especially in this case I think he should care about speed: I've just made a little benchmark and it turns out that `Concat` is about 3x faster than `Union`.

Comment: @AS-CII Under what conditions?  This is linq to SQL, I am pretty sure the difference between the two would be Linq Union() generates a SQL UNION where Linq Concat() generates a SQL UNION ALL.  But I will change it to Concat() rather than union as it is technically more correct.

Comment: @Ben, +1. Now I'm really happy. :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the [Codeplex Fluent Linq to SQL project](http://fluentlinqtosql.codeplex.com/).  I've never used it, but I'm familiar with the ideas from using similar mapping techniques in EF4.  YOu could create a single object and map it dynamically to different tables using syntax such as:

```
public class LogMapping : Mapping<Log> {
    public LogMapping(int year) {
        Named("Logs" + year);
        //Column mappings...
    }
}
```

Comment: That project hasn't been updated since 2008 and is no longer under active development.  Looks nice in theory though.

Comment: @Ben, the same could be said for Winforms and LINQ to SQL as well. If the technology is mature, it may not need to be under active development.

Comment: @Steve by using this fluent Linq to Sql would i be able to map the log table structure so i can use it on any classes or methods i want? Is that it? Because if it is, it solves my problem.

Comment: In theory it is.  Like I said I've never used it, but with Fluent EF4, that's exactly how it would work.

Comment: +1: I'll have to add dynamic mappings to a legacy LINQ to SQL application, and this seems to fit perfectly, thanks.