# C# child class losing property value

Tags: c#, generics, exception, abstract-class

Due to a recent issue i had some days ago (you can check this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179436/c-linq-to-sql-selecting-tables-dynamically)), i needed to create a way that some of my linq to sql tables could be referenced dynamically. I've managed to do that through an abstract LogTable class, which contains all my LogTable properties as defined on my DataTable. I was able to do this abstract way because my LogTables have the same structure, thus the same properties.

Heres the reducted code:

*Abstract base class*

```
public abstract class LogTableStructure
{
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public datetime? LastAccess { get; set; }

        public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

My (reducted) dynamic method to update a LogTable:

```
public void UpdateLog<T>(T currentLOG) where T : LogTableStructure
    {

        LogTableStructure logStructure = null;

        //LogTableEnum is defined on this class constructor
        switch (LogTableEnum)
        {
            case LogTableEnum.Log2009:
                logStructure = this.factory.LogDB.LOG_2009s
                    .SingleOrDefault(q => q.ID == currentLOG.ID);
                break;
            case LogTableEnum.Log2010:
                logStructure = this.factory.LogDB.LOG_2010s
                    .SingleOrDefault(q => q.ID == currentLOG.ID);
                break;
            case LogTableEnum.Log2011:
                logStructure = this.factory.LogDB.LOG_2011s
                    .SingleOrDefault(q => q.ID == currentLOG.ID);
                break;
   }
}
```

**PROBLEM**

for some reason the currentLOG param throws a runtime null reference exception, even though it has all LogTable properties filled. I've notice by using vs2010 debbuger that while the currentLOG properties are filled, the base class (LogTableStructure) properties are all empty, as if the base object is null.

Am i forgeting something about member hide inheritance or something alike? I've even added the `new` modifier to all my LogTable properties on my .dbml, but even that didn't solve the problem

Comment: Can you give an example of code where you call the `UpdateLog` method? Also, where do you define the `ocorrenciaBanco` object you're injecting into?

Comment: What is `ocorrenciaBanco`? Why are you declaring a `logStructure` variable which you're then ignoring? What do you mean by "the currentLOG param throws [...]"? (The parameter itself can't throw an exception - only access can.)

Comment: Are you aware of the typo in the last case statement? Should be Log2011, I guess..

Comment: Sorry, that was another piece of code that came with my ctrl + c. I've edited it now.

Comment: Where is the variable `LogTableStucture` you're filling declared?

Comment: How is `LogTableStructure logStructure = null; logStructure.InjectFrom(currentLOG);` ever meant to work? Looks like that will throw an exception if it's a normal method, or do nothing useful if it's an extension method...

Comment: @JonSkeet How silly :) this was a new test i was doing and didnt occur to me that would always throw an null reference exception. However, now that i have erased this section of my code, i'm having a `TargetInvocationException`

Comment: @AdrianoRR: Then I suggest you look at the nested exception *within* the TargetInvocationException.

Comment: @JonSkeet tsc, my previous ctrl + c mistake almost made me forget the main problem. The exception nested inside `TargetInvocation` was once again `NullReferenceException`. And i know why this is happening. It's because the compiler can't recognize any filled properties from my `currentLog` param. If it doesnt have any values at all, it will never find any log from my database. And this is the problem: why am i losing the param properties, considering that i can see them when debbuging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the object into which you're injecting an actual instance:

```
// This object is going to have to be a class that inherits from your abstract class
// It can't be a null object of the type of your abstract class.
var logStructure = new InstanceOfLogTableStructure();
logStructure.InjectFrom(currentLOG);
```

That should do it.

Comment: LogTableStructure is an abstract class, i can't instantiate it.

Comment: Sorry about that...you're going to need to instantiate *some* class. You can't inject into a null instance of an abstract class.

Comment: I've converted my abstract class to a commom class, so that i can inject it. Guess what, for some reason, even though all LogTables properties were null, i could update my values. I don't like the idea of using a code that i don't understand it's behavior, so i'll continue to search a better solution. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: The way ValueInjecter (or any automapper-like utility) works is that it uses reflection to compare properties and values of two instances of classes. Your initial code was trying to declare a variable of the type of your abstract class, but without an actual class instance ValueInjecter doesn't have any values to inspect. You've since changed your post and I can't see where you do that injection now, but hopefully that explanation sheds some light.

Comment: yes, it shed a light on my problem :) Well, since it seems that i can't explain correctly what _was_ (it's not perfect yet) the problem, i guess i'll try to post a printScreen later.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have your ordering wrong. You're assigning null to logStructure, then you're calling InjectFrom on it. Only then are you assigning a factory-created instance to that variable.